# how to make counting in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

i have a table that "users"

i want to count their salary who have ID 1 and 2

how i can count this in mysql

Comment: count means sum if so use SUM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Aggregate Functions in MySQL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx) and [GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

**to get total salary of both**

```
SELECT SUM(salary) FROM users WHERE id IN(1, 2);
```

**and to get individual sum of salary**

```
SELECT SUM(salary) FROM users WHERE id IN(1, 2) group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(salary) FROM users WHERE id IN(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I shall refer you to counting rows from the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)

probably goes like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE id IN (1,2);
```

although if you're actually trying to sum the salaries then you should refer to [group by functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
SELECT id, SUM(salary) FROM users WHERE id IN (1,2) GROUP BY id;
```